# Bool does not exist in current context but declared in same way as other variables

Tags: c#

I have a bool that the compiler says does not exist in the current scope, however all the other variable are declared and used in the same place/way. Code below, some class names changed and code simplified but the structure remains the same.

`iDReq does not exist in the current context`

```
if (button.Click) {
    string sourceFileName = "";
    string destPathFileName = "";
    int exportCount = 0;
    bool iDReq = true;
    iDReq = (System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Include ID in file names?", "ID",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes); 
    foreach (KeyValueCollection item in SearchControl.SelectedItems)
    {
        Class.Document doc = Class.Document.GetDocument((long)item["id"].Value);
        {
            sourceFileName = @"\\server\share" + @"\" + Convert.ToString(doc.GetExtraInfo("docFileName"));
            string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(sourceFileName);     
            //Line below is the one that the compiler does not like.                                
            iDReq = true ? destPathFileName = destPath + @"" + doc.Description + " " + "(" + doc.ID + ")" + fileExtension : destPathFileName = destPath + @"" + doc.Description + fileExtension;
                try {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destPath);
                    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName,destPathFileName,true); 
                    System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(destPathFileName);
                    exportCount ++;
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ErrorBox.Show(ex); 
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it because it's a boolean value or am I missing something else?

Comment: I'm not at all clear on why you're trying to perform assignments inside of a conditional operator but that's not going to work. It's unclear what you thought you were assigning to `idReq` there.

Comment: remove your ternary and write a if/else to debug.

Comment: I'm pretty sure ternary ifs don't work like that...

Comment: ternary operator doesn't work like that.

Comment: `idReq` is being assigned to the user's choice on the message box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your ternary is badly written, but I am not sure about what you want. I would rewrite you this as a plain `if/else`. I love ternary operator, but it is just sugar.

I think you are looking for this:

```
destPathFileName = iDReq == true
    ? (destPath + @"" + doc.Description + " " + "(" + doc.ID + ")" + fileExtension)
    : (destPath + @"" + doc.Description + fileExtension);
```

and `iDReq == true` is superflous.

also you can write:

```
destPathFileName = destPath + @"" + doc.Description
    + (iDReq ? " (" + doc.ID + ")" : string.Empty)
    + fileExtension;
```

by the way, `@""` is `string.Empty`.

and with string interpolation:

```
destPathFileName = destPath + doc.Description
    + (iDReq ? $" ({doc.ID})" : string.Empty)
    + fileExtension;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, the middle one. I think my ternary was the wrong syntax.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
destPathFileName  = iDReq ? destPath + @"" + doc.Description + " " + "(" + doc.ID + ")" + fileExtension : destPath + @"" + doc.Description + fileExtension;
```

Comment: @aloisdg No need to put `iDReq == true`. This is just another type of answer

Comment: `iDReq == true` is not a problem. It is just superflous.